How to properly use poetry with different versions of python on windows?
I am trying to migrate our projects to using Poetry. What I want to achieve is when people open the project using PyCharm, it will automatically create the environment using Poetry and install dependencies. PyCharm does support this, however, when a different Python version is being specified on pyproject.toml file, it cannot find the executable.
This is due to the newly installed Python versions not being added to the PATH environment variable. From what I have read this is normal.
As the Python launcher correctly identifies the versions, I am able to get the path of the Python interpreter executable using py and pass it to poetry with this line:
poetry env use (py -3.9 -c "import sys; print(sys.executable)")

However this requires user input which goes against what I was trying to do with setting up the environment using PyCharm.
What is the ideal way to make poetry env use 3.x working on Windows when I am working with multiple versions? Does pyenv help with this problem?

If the user input is known then you can put it in a text file and use it as input using < filename.
